# how to increase heap space of JVM in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

On running my code it throws exception:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

How to increase the heap space of JVM in netbeans 8??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run->Set Project Configuration->Customize...
You can enter your VM options in Run tab. Use the -Xmx[size] flag to increase the heap size.
As size you can use for example 512m for 512MB or 2g for 2000MB.

Comment: Help me with a Xmx size.
running the code shows
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx
Java Result: 1

Comment: You have to give a value for the size, such as `512m` for 512 megabytes, or `2g` for 2 gigabytes. The actual value you use will depend on your application and the amount of memory on your computer.

Comment: How do you have it set? What is the exact switch you're passing to it?

Comment: @user3759600  Would be useful to know how it went from not working to working. I am still getting the error.